# MongoDB return flat array from aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I would like to have my aggregation query return a flat array instead of an array of objects exactly like [`.distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) does.

Example Document:

```js
{
    type: 'pageview',
    url: 'https://example.com/something',
    visitorId: '5df7c38abbdb1506dc048451'
}
```

Example Aggregation:

```js
db.accounts.events.aggregate( [
    // First stage
    { $match: { url: 'https://example.com/something' } },
    // Second stage
    { $group: { _id: "$visitorId", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
    // Third stage
    { $match: { count: { $gt: 10 } } }
] )
```

Returns:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5df7c38abbdb1506dc048451"), "count" : 13 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5df7c38abbdb1506dc048454"), "count" : 18 }
// ... and so forth
```

**Should return:**

```js
[ ObjectId("5df7c38abbdb1506dc048451"), ObjectId("5df7c38abbdb1506dc048454") ]
```

I know that its fairly easy to do on the client side, but I wonder if mongodb is capable of doing it right within the aggregation as well.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you something close to your expected result:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // First stage
    { $match: { url: 'https://example.com/something' } },
    // Second stage
    { $group: { _id: "$visitorId", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
    // Third stage
    { $match: { count: { $gt: 10 } } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            data: {
                $push: "$_id"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            data: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$data",
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: {
                        $concatArrays: ["$$value", ["$$this"]]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "data": [
            ObjectId("5df7c38abbdb1506dc048451"),
            ObjectId("5df7c38abbdb1506dc048454")
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

[Definiton of db.collection.aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#definition) says that an Aggregation:

> Returns: A cursor to the documents produced by the final stage of the
>   aggregation pipeline operation, ...

The returned cursor has documents, and a document always has a *key* and a *value*, as defined in the [MongoDB document structure](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/index.html#document-structure).

So, the way to get an array of *values* (only) is to use one of the ways described in the already posted answers and the following discussions (i.e., by applying the [cursor methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/index.html) on the returned cursor by the aggregation).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` on the aggregate to return a flat array of a desired field value:

```
db.accounts.events.aggregate( [
  // First stage
   { $match: { url: 'https://example.com/something' } },
  // Second stage
   { $group: { _id: "$visitorId", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
  // Third stage
   { $match: { count: { $gt: 10 } } }
]).map(function(obj) { return obj._id })
```

Here is a method utilizing mongo. The thing is, it returns an object with a flat array within. Aggregation will always return an object, unfortunately. You can chain an aggregate with .cursor().exec() in order to get the `.toArray()` method, but I'm not sure if that will help you here:

```
db.accounts.events.aggregate( [
  // First stage
   { $match: { url: 'https://example.com/something' } },
  // Second stage
   { $group: { _id: "$visitorId", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
  // Third stage
   { $match: { count: { $gt: 10 } } },
   {
    $project:{array:true,_id:false}
   }
])
```

Comment: Thanks. I am aware that I can do it with a simple map on the client side but thats why I was asking if there is a way to do it directly within the mongodb aggregation :)

Comment: @Snowball this isn't on the client... the `.map` method is available in the aggregate you are calling on the server.

Comment: I mean the mongodb definition of client and server side. So even if you are running your mongodb client on a server with node.js it is the mongodb client (side) while the aggregation runs on the mongodb server. The $match and $group stuff is no native JavaScript, but executed by mongodb on the server. The .map() is native JavaScript being executed on the "client side".

Comment: @Snowball I got ya, my apologies. I updated my answer. It may not be sufficient for you, but perhaps it will help.